# How get layerID or Layer name from marker

Tags: leaflet

I can get marker but I want to get the layer ID or name from markers so as to filter markers.

```js
var overLayers = [
{
    name: "Bar",
    icon: iconByName('bar'),
    layer: L.geoJson(Bar,{onEachFeature: onEachFeature}),
    group: "Bar",
    markerType:"accordion",
    active:true
}];
```

Get markers function

```js
function getAllMarkers() {

 var allMarkersObjArray = []; // for marker objects
 var allMarkersGeoJsonArray = []; // for readable geoJson markers

 $.each(map._layers, function (ml) {

     if (map._layers[ml].feature) {

         allMarkersObjArray.push(this)
         allMarkersGeoJsonArray.push(JSON.stringify(this.toGeoJSON()))
     }
 })

 console.log(allMarkersObjArray);
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion.

Comment: Could you kindly share more details on what you try to achieve? You would have several ways of "filtering" markers, most simple would be to store them in different Layer Groups, possibly right from when they are created by `L.geoJson`.

Comment: For a given marker, I would like to know which layer it belong to. How should I do?  Can I set layer's option in L.geoJson?

Comment: Hi ghybs,  I have a dropdown list control and then user will select one of options. After that, It will go to find marker that corresponds to the option user select.  In this case, I get all markers but I don't know which layer the marker belong to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you were looking for the `layer._leaflet_id` attribute.

See the added line - that should give you the current marker id (note that the `_leaflet_id` is in the layer's attributes and not in the feature's attributes).

```
$.each(map._layers, function (ml) {

     if (map._layers[ml].feature) {
         var marker_id =  map._layers[ml]._leaflet_id
         allMarkersObjArray.push(this)
         allMarkersGeoJsonArray.push(JSON.stringify(this.toGeoJSON()))
     }
 })
```

I think `this._leaflet_id` will work as well.

EDIT:
After further inquiries I found that Util [L.stamp()](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#util-stamp) is the proper approach, the method returns the unique id of an object or assigning one to it.

```
$.each(map._layers, function (ml) {   
     if (map._layers[ml].feature) {
         var marker_id =  L.stamp(map._layers[ml])
         allMarkersObjArray.push(this)
         allMarkersGeoJsonArray.push(JSON.stringify(this.toGeoJSON()))
     }
 })
```

Comment: Thanks, I give it a try. My current solution is to get markers from layer and compare them.

Comment: using properties that are demarked with a _ seems like it's accessing properties that are meant to be private, no? Or does leaflet not follow that style?

Comment: You are correct, I thought it's the only way to achieve this property. The good style-wise answer is using L.stamp(), I will add another answer.